# How to programmatically modify a IF condition to a NOT IF

Tags: java

I have a source code file which consist of several if conditions. I would Like to make all these **if** conditions to **not if** conditions programmatically, using java as the programming language.

ex:

```
if (format == OutputFormat.SIMPLIFY) return format_simplify();
```

to

```
if (!(format == OutputFormat.SIMPLIFY)) return format_simplify();
```

Please let me know how I should perform this task in java.

Comment: I would use a regex to replace the pattern "if(*)" to "if(!(*))", but I am not sure yet how to perform that. Perhaps it would be easier with `sed`. I don't know how tricky it gets when the same if condition spreads through several lines though...

Answer (score 0):

replace `format == OutputFormat.SIMPLIFY` with `IsNotSimplify(format)` and add the function is the way I'd do it.

Perhaps there's a better name though...

Comment: I replied you.. Thanks for understanding!

Answer (score 0):

That should do the job:

```
(if\s*\()([^\)]*)(.*)
```

With weplace pattern :

```
$1 !($2) $3
```

It will only work for simple conditions that does not contain brackets.
Otherwise, you will need a lexer to perform this task.

Answer (score -1):

For you to know: If you need to do that your design would have a serious flaw. Fortunatelly for you, you don't need to do that. You need to evaluate an extra condition to decide whether use one operator or the other.

I would suggest to have a boolean variable (say equality = false) and substitute your code above with:

```
if (equality)
if (format == OutputFormat.SIMPLIFY) return format_simplify();
else
if (!(format == OutputFormat.SIMPLIFY)) return format_simplify();
```

Comment: Whoever add the negative: What are you playing at? A simple answer for a simple question that doesn't need a deeper insight.

Comment: Your code duplicates the entire body of the code that way, and that's making flawed code a lot worse, possibly encouraging bad habits. The other answers contribute more in the sense that they focus on extending the condition rather than duplication.